# OnClick of a Button display the next page

Tags: blackberry, button, buttonclick

I am a newbie to Blackberry,could anyone please let me know how to go to the next page on click of a Button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// inside of your current screen:
ButtonField btn = new ButtonField("Go to next screen");
btn.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field f, int arg1) {
        NextScreen ns = new NextScreen();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(ns);
    }
});
add(btn);
```

Comment: Don't forget the ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK style bit.  Otherwise the click will also bring up the context menu.

Comment: Yes, pass this style as a second argument of ButtonField constructor.